# Attendance Sheet of Student in "jquery" dynamic

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, time-and-attendance

I am creating an attendance sheet in which a student add a pin code for attendance but there is the problem, when I try to add pin code of first and last person, etc then only these students are marked by 'present'(P) but others not shown "Absent".

I am using HTML, CSS bootstrap and also for dynamic creating I am using jquery.

Check this link I upload the code. I have no experience with jquery.

I expect the output of the code is when we enter two or three-person pin code only those have 'P' but others have 'A' or Absent.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/MuneeburRehman/d12Lp8cn/2/)

```js
var pin;
// var inde=60;
var inde = 10;

function timer1() {
  t = setInterval(next, 1000);
}

function next() {
  inde--;
  $('#timer').html("00:" + (inde > 9 ? inde + "s" : "0" + inde + "s"));
  if (inde == 0) {
    clearInterval(t);
    $('#timer').html("00:" + "00");
    $("#att").slideUp(); // for 1st thing
    $("#tablee").slideDown(5000); //for table
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  timer1();
  $("#check").click(function() {
    pin = $("#txt1").val();
    if (pin == "1111") {
      $('#p1').fadeOut();
      $('#hh1').fadeIn();
      $('#txt1').css("border", "2px solid green");
      $('#check').css("border", "2px solid green");
      $('#check').css("background-color", "green");
      console.log("1");
      $("#hh1").html("Usama you are Present!");
      var a1 = $('#s18').append('<b>P</b>').css("color", "darkgreen");
      // $("#s28 ,#s38,#s48,#s58,#s68").html('<b>A</b>').css("color","red");

    } else if (pin == "1212") {
      $('#p1').fadeOut();
      $('#hh1').fadeIn();
      $('#txt1').css("border", "2px solid green");
      $('#check').css("border", "2px solid green");
      $('#check').css("background-color", "green");
      console.log("2");
      $("#hh1").html("Muneeb you are Present!");
      var a2 = $('#s28').append('<b>P</b>').css("color", "darkgreen");
      // $(' #s38, #s48, #s58, #s68').html('<b>A</b>').css("color","red");
    } else if (pin == "1313") {
      $('#p1').fadeOut();
      $('#hh1').fadeIn();
      $('#txt1').css("border", "2px solid green");
      $('#check').css("border", "2px solid green");
      $('#check').css("background-color", "green");
      console.log("3");
      $("#hh1").html("Hamza you are Present!");
      var a3 = $('#s38').append('<b>P</b>').css("color", "darkgreen");
      // $(' #s48, #s58, #s68').html('<b>A</b>').css("color","red");
    } else if (pin == "1414") {
      $('#p1').fadeOut();
      $('#hh1').fadeIn();
      $('#txt1').css("border", "2px solid green");
      $('#check').css("border", "2px solid green");
      $('#check').css("background-color", "green");
      console.log("4");
      $("#hh1").html("Hassan you are Present!");
      var a4 = $('#s48').append('<b>P</b>').css("color", "darkgreen");
      // $(' #s58, #s68').html('<b>A</b>').css("color","red");
    } else if (pin == "1515") {
      $('#p1').fadeOut();
      $('#hh1').fadeIn();
      $('#txt1').css("border", "2px solid green");
      $('#check').css("border", "2px solid green");
      $('#check').css("background-color", "green");
      $("#hh1").html("Ahmed you are Present!");
      console.log("5");
      var a5 = $('#s58').append('<b>P</b>').css("color", "darkgreen");
      // $(' #s68').html('<b>A</b>').css("color","red");    
    } else if (pin == "1616") {
      $('#p1').fadeOut();
      $('#hh1').fadeIn();
      $('#txt1').css("border", "2px solid green");
      $('#check').css("border", "2px solid green");
      $('#check').css("background-color", "green");
      $("#hh1").html("Taimoor you are Present!");
      console.log("6");
      var a6 = $('#s68').append('<b>P</b>').css("color", "darkgreen");
      // $('#s18,#s28, #s38, #s48, #s58').html('<b>A</b>').css("color","red");

    } else {
      console.log("10");
      $('#hh1').fadeOut();
      $('#txt1').css("border", "2px solid red");
      $('#check').css("border", "2px solid red");
      $('#check').css("background-color", "red");
      $('#p1').fadeIn();
      $('#s18,#s28, #s38, #s48, #s58, #s68').append('<b>A</b>').css("color", "red");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#p1,
#tablee {
  display: none;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="timer" style="padding-left:80%; ">01m:00s</h1>

<div class="container-fluid " id="tablee" style="padding-top:5%">
  <h1 style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 2%">Attendance Sheet</h1>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-md " style="text-align: center;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col" colspan="16">Attendance</th>
        <th scope="col">Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Usama</td>
        <td id="">P</td>
        <td id="">P</td>
        <td id="">A</td>
        <td id="s18"></td>

        <td id=""></td>
        <!-- For Total -->
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Muneeb</td>
        <td id="">P</td>
        <td id="">P</td>
        <td id="">A</td>
        <td id="s28"></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <!-- For Total -->
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Hamza</td>
        <td id="">P</td>
        <td id="">P</td>
        <td id="">A</td>
        <td id="s38"></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <!-- For Total -->
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">4</th>
        <td>Hassan</td>
        <td id="">A</td>
        <td id="">P</td>
        <td id="">P</td>
        <td id="s48"></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <!-- For Total -->
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">5</th>
        <td>Ahmed</td>
        <td id="">P</td>
        <td id="">P</td>
        <td id="">P</td>
        <td id="s58"></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <!-- For Total -->
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">6</th>
        <td>Taimoor</td>
        <td id="">A</td>
        <td id="">A</td>
        <td id="">A</td>
        <td id="s68"></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <td id=""></td>
        <!-- For Total -->
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<center>



  <div style="padding-top:4%" id="att">

    <label>Please Insert Your Pin for your Attendance: </label>
    <input type="text" id="txt1">
    <button id="check">Check</button><br><br>
    <h4 id="hh1"></h4>
    <!-- <a href="try2.html"><button id="access">Check your Attendance</button></a> -->
    <p id='p1' style="color: red"><b>You didn't Access Attendance Sheet Please insert Correct Pin..!</b></p>
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. Post that information HERE at SO - you were asked to NOT post JSFiddle without code

Comment: @mplungjan check this link    https://jsfiddle.net/MuneeburRehman/j391t7fn/4/         When i click on total button it check which person is absent or does not enter the right pin code